# Visual Studio 2015 missing 'Add Fakes...' option

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have VS 2015 professional with update 2 and am missing the option to add a fakes assembly:

[image]

I use this same project on a different machine using VS 2013 and can add fakes fine to that. Am I meant to do something different in 2015?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the answer, fakes in Visual Studio 2015 are only available in the Enterprise version. I thought it was Professional and above.

[MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx)

> Requirements:
>
> Visual Studio Enterprise

Comment: But in Enterprise Edition StubIServiceProvider not generating from System.Fakes Assembly

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Fakes assemblies in the references. You can see that orange triangle in ServiceAgents.Fakes reference. You need import this reference first.

Comment: That's a fake that I've created using a different machine. My instance of VS doesn't seem to recognise fakes

Answer (score 0):

You can download Visual studio 2012 premium with update 2 and you can find option to add fake assembly, this option I didn't find out in vs 2015